# RVM won't switch to OS X system ruby

Tags: rvm

I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.1, I install rvm stable (after running `rvm implode` to clear it out), then install 1.9.3. However, it's impossible to switch back to the system ruby.

```
rvm use system
# -> Now using system ruby.
ruby -v
# -> ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
/usr/bin/ruby -v
# -> ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
echo $PATH
# -> /Users/agnoster/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/agnoster/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/agnoster/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/n/current/bin:/Users/agnoster/.yadr/bin:/Users/agnoster/.yadr/bin/yadr:/Users/agnoster/.rvm/bin
type rvm | head -n1
# rvm is a shell function
```

This wouldn't bother me much, except that it also won't install a new 1.8.7 and I have some gems I'd like to test again 1.8.7. Travis is nice here, but I'd really prefer to be able to run 1.8.7 locally.

It looks like rvm is just cowardly refusing to fix the path. If I manually strip all .rvm-1.9.3-related stuff from the PATH, if works. Why isn't rvm doing that itself?

Answer (score 0):

you found a bug with resetting `PATH` on zsh - this should be reported as an bug: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues